# Combining two unsigned bytes to a single integer value using left-shift and bitwise-or

Tags: c, integer, bit-manipulation

I'm reading 2 bytes which together build up an `unsigned short` value, from 0 to 65536. I want to combine them to a single value, so here what I've done:

```
int32_t temp; 
uint8_t buffer[2]; 

.............
temp = (buffer[1] << 8) /* [MSByte]*/| (buffer[0]/* [LSByte]*/);

printf (" %d" ,temp) ;
```

I still get an overflow at 32767. Any idea why?

Comment: How is `Buffer` declared?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking nor what you are trying to do.

Comment: @iharob I've added the declaration of buffer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cast byte to int before shifting, i.e.:

```
((int32_t)buffer[1] << 8) | buffer[0]
```

---

P.S. 2 bytes can store an unsigned integer value in range of [0, 65535]; the value of 65536 you've mentioned is out of range.

---

Complete test program — try different byte values in `buffer`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
//uint8_t buffer[2] = {255, 0  }; // prints   255
//uint8_t buffer[2] = {255, 127}; // prints 32767
  uint8_t buffer[2] = {255, 255}; // prints 65535

  int32_t temp = ((int32_t)buffer[1] << 8) | buffer[0];

  printf("%d", temp);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I still got the overflow

Comment: @Engine seems to me like the `%d` in `printf` causing the problem, because `%d` is for `int` but your `int` seem to be `int16_t`. Try C99 format `printf(PRIi32, temp)` ? http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer

Comment: it works fine now thanks to all of you for your help